# Common exception handler

Tags: c#, c++, exception

There is a big app, with thousands of exception handlers in the code like:

```
try {
   ...
}
catch (OurException ex) {
   ...
}
```

Now the request is that, if OurException.Code == NNN, then some extra special tasks should be done. Always, everywhere.
Is there any better/faster way **than changing thousands of source location** like:

```
void HandleSpecialCase(OurException ex) { 
   if (ex.Code == NNN) ... 
}

try {
   ...
}
catch (OurException ex) {
   HandleSpecialCase(ex);
   ... rest
}
```

Any idea for C# or C++ would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** my question is really about: I don't want to go through all the thousands of source files, all the ten thousands of exception handlers in the code, and change those one by one.

Comment: Is it c# or c++ - those are very (!) different things

Comment: Can you do some work in the `Exception`'s constructor?

Comment: @GiladGreen yes, but would the answer to this question be very different?

Comment: @GiladGreen Code has both C# and C++ source, for C++, it's simpler, as most of the exception handling is done by Macros, so one place to change, but not all (so any idea welcome here as well). For C#, all like in my question, so no common place at all currently.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, yes, we have to OurException class source as well, and I also thought of that, but that is not a nice programming paradigm, the Exception class itself should not do any "handler related" tasks.

Comment: I really, really hope the above example is C# since otherwise you're slicing your exceptions (by not catching them by reference)

Comment: Code which uses lots of local exception handlers represents a broken design.   It is usually better to centralise exception handling as much as possible, and write most code in a system so exceptions pass through cleanly, and have a small number of exception handling codes that handle the majority of exceptions ever thrown.   A large system which doesn't do this - as you are finding - becomes a maintenance nightmare very quickly.

Comment: @UKMonkey, yes, that is C#, but does not matter, could be pseudo code as well to explain the situation.

Comment: @Peter, not necessarily, for example UI/Windows event handlers has to be there.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about C#, but in C++, what about using polymorphism?

```
class OurException {
  virtual void handle() = 0;
};

class SpecialCaseException : public OurException {
  static const int code = NNN;

  virtual void handle() {
     // do what you need to
  }
};
```

Then you just use:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (OurException& ex) {
  // This is executed for OurException and all its derived classes
  ex.handle();
  // ... rest
}
```

Exceptions are already expensive (when thrown), so I don't think the cost of run-time data type checking is going to make much of a difference.

If you don't want to change the try/catch blocks, then the solution will not be clean. Probably will not be correct either, but you can try the following:

```
class OurException {
  OurException( Code c ) :
     code(c)
  {
     if( c == NNN ) {
        // handle special case
     }
  }
};
```

Note that the constructor will be called before the exception is thrown.

Comment: This will still require to change thousands of code location...basically every exception handler. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Then, since the try/catch block takes a value and not a reference of the exception, you might be able to do it at OurException constructor, which is not the greatest idea. The idea of polymorphism is specifically avoid the kind of problem you have just found, but this time it seems to come too late.

Comment: See my comment above: "yes, we have to OurException class source as well, and I also thought of that, but that is not a nice programming paradigm, the Exception class itself should not do any "handler related" tasks. "

Comment: Agree, but you know in many cases you will deal with a trade-off: you can't make a decision and expect to win in every single aspect.

Comment: Agree...I also cannot figure out other "solution"..except change everywhere in the code

Comment: If you expect that in the future the number of *special cases* will grow, then I think it is worth the effort. Using automatic substitution is the way to go in such case, with tools like `sed` and `awk` or solutions such as the one @AtulKumar explained

Answer (score 0):

If you find no language specific answer, one option could be to use PowerShell to get the list of all locations in code using `(OurException .. {` and then running another script to insert `HandleSpecialCase(ex);` in the next line. A crude way but it will do the work for most of locations.

Below will find all the files

```
ls -Path . -Filter *.java  -File -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "\(Exception" | ft path, LineNumber, Line | out-file exceptionlocations.txt
```

This can be your validation that right instances are found.

You can then write powershell script that will first enumerate all the locations using line

```
$locations = ls -Path . -Filter *.java  -File -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "\(Exception"
```

Run this output in loop to read file content using `get-content` which will give it in an array, insert the line `HandleSpecialCase(ex);` in array after the line where we found match and then use `set-content` to write back whole array to same file path.

Comment: Thanks, that is basically the same, changing every source, but with a tool. Of course, if not better option, I should consider.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't want a

```
try {
}
catch (MyException e) {
    switch(e.code) {
    }
}
```

but a

```
try {
}
catch (SpecialException e) {
}
catch (OtherSpecialException e) {
}
catch (MyException e) {
}
```

If you wanted the same thing done in every catch, then you can just write a script that replaces 'catch (MyException)' with the everything else.

Comment: The problem with this is that, by the time you need to add yet another special exception, you have to modify all the try/catch blocks again to add the additional block.

Comment: @JorgeBellón Well, let's be honest about this - the design of the app is wrong.  It sounds like the Exceptions aren't exceptional; and they're being used for program flow.  By splitting it up a little, it should highlight which exceptions are being used for flow and can be binned.

Comment: Yes, @JorgeBellón is right, that's what I wanted to avoid. I would not say necessarily design is wrong, as for GUI event handlers for example, you must handle.

Comment: Exactly. In user interfaces a slowdown to report the error is way more important than crashing the application, so using exceptions on the visual layers is common to see (e.g.: show a specific error dialog) . If the exceptions are not used in the computation hot spot it does not make any difference performance-wise, since the humans' response time is way slower than computers'.